# Проблемы с деинсталлятором

Tags: c#, installutil

Решил написать инсталлятор, все написал, проверил, добавил в реестр записи. При написании деинсталлятора проблема - Всплывает диалог: правильно ли работала моя программа?... Хорошо, что эти проблемы только на 7, на ХР все работает нормально. Может кто знает как обновить панель и убрать это сообщение. Ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: может быть ей нужны права администратора?

Comment: я бы использовал какое ни будь готовое решение инсталлятора... Их более чем полно...

Comment: не знаю, по идее нет, кстати, из списка программ я удалил программу, так что осталось только этот диалог убрать.

Comment: @metalurgus, не подскажите какие есть простые, бесплатные, с возможностью написания своего кода, причем и с отладкой?

Comment: install sheld помоему бесплатный и к тому же нативный

Comment: занимайтесь сами с этим нативным гавном

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону NSIS, использовал в нескольких проектах, вполне доволен.